# Nested table elements query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, nested

MSSQL
I have `T1` table with `Id` and `name` columns. Like in previous question but there another task.

Table `T2` with `Aggregate_ID` and `Element_ID`.

They are crossed

x1:

```
ID и Name

1 Car
2 Hood
3 Engine
4 Cylinder 
5 Wheel
6 tyre
7 rim (car)
8 Rim fixation (Car)
```

x2:

```
Aggregate_ID Element_ID

1 2
1 3 
1 5 
3 4
5 6
5 7
7 8
```

I need to output all the simplest elements of which consists aggregate like Wheel. It would be 6,8 in the case of wheel.
To  "car" it would be 2,4,6,8
The level on nesting can be changed. This is simple example. But level of nesting can be 4,5..20 or unlimited.

I read this http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx but I can`t handle it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query. It uses common table expressions. The first section gets the aggregate that is the parameter. The second section adds next aggregates recursively.

Then I select those aggregates that are leaves of this tree (are not parents).

```
declare @part as varchar(max) = 'wheel'

;with cte
as
(

    select aggregate_id, element_id
    from t2 where aggregate_id = (select id from t1 where name = @part)

    union all

    select t2.aggregate_id, t2.element_id
    from t2
    inner join cte on cte.element_id = t2.aggregate_id
)

select distinct c1.element_id from cte c1
where not exists (select * from cte c2 where c1.element_id = c2.aggregate_id)
```

Comment: Thanks. I would learn. How can I do it with no recursion? Cycles?